# java.lang.String#isEmpty() vs org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils#isEmpty()

Tags: java, string, apache-commons

While the description of oracles method says it returns true only if the length of the string is 0, the string utils methods description says the method also checks the string for being 'null'. What method should I use then? If the string has a length of 0 (e. g. "") it automatically is not 'null' or if I made my string to be 'null' and then check its emptyness with oracles method I would get 'false', so isn't the nullcheck of the apaches method redundant or am I completely wrong with my thoughts? Please help me to understand the difference!

Comment: How should `myString.isEmpty()` work if `myString` is `null`? -> *"I made my string to be 'null' and then check its emptyness with oracles method I would get 'false'"*, no you would get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: if you'll check a null string with oracle's `isEmpty()` you'll get a NPE

Comment: Well, it works in the apache version

Comment: just did not know oracles method throws a NPE

Comment: if using oracle's method just check`if (s != null && !s.isEmpty())`

Comment: Maybe you didn't know it, because you didn't spend a few minutes to test both approaches?

Comment: @Tom you are right. Thought of doing this a bit too late.

Comment: It is never too late to test something :) and if you doesn't understand something, then you can ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would edge towards always using the apache version.  The Oracle version requires you to have a non-null String as it is an instance method, e.g.

```
String s = null;
s.isEmpty(); <--- throws a NullPointerException
StringUtils.isEmpty(s); <--- returns true
```

If you don't want to include commons-lang in your project you can achieve the same functionality using

```
s != null && s.isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apache method is useful when you do not know if a string has been set or not.

```
if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print(s)
}
```

vs

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
    System.out.print(s)
}
```

It will make you code more concise